# MySQL subselect count returns 1

Tags: mysql, select, count

I have a piece of code that should return a count of 4, but only comes back with a count of 1. This is my query.

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` IN (`enc_vs`) AND `rpg_curr_hp` > 0) AS playerCount FROM `encounter` WHERE `enc_id` = 32
```

The row with enc_id of 32 in `encounter` has a group of user id's which are 1,62,12,23 and that is enc_vs. When I do the count with numbers, it works and returns a count of 4. But when I use `enc_vs` instead, it comes back as 1.

This would result in:

```
enc_id |   enc_vs   | playerCount
   32    1,62,12,23        1
```

The users table looks something like

```
user_id | rpg_curr_hp
   1         55
   2         50
   3         55
[all the way down to]
  12         57
  62         55
etc...
```

The `enc_vs` is a string of id's for the users table.
I need it to result in

```
enc_id |   enc_vs   | playerCount
   32    1,62,12,23        4
```

assuming that all 4 players have a rpg_curr_hp greater than zero.

EDIT: THIS IS REGARDING A COUNT, NOT A SEARCH FOR COLUMNS.

Comment: provide some data samples

Comment: not sure if my guess is correct but try to replace `IN`  with `FIND_IN_SET` function

Comment: Yeah, Alex is right. Sounds like you've got a comma-delimited string and that won't work like you expected.

Comment: if you have a comma delimited column...refactor

Comment: I'll provide some samples, just not immediately.. doing multiple things right now.
The value for `enc_vs` for the record in question is '1,62,12,23'. But this results in 1.
But if I replace `enc_vs` with with 1,62,12,23, the count will result in 4. Which is what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: It is absolutely unclear what you are talking about. Please provide clear data samples and expected result, as well as current (wrong one) you have

Comment: Updated my post in an attempt to explain a little clearer. I appreciate your patience since explaining things isn't really my strongest aspect of myself. :(

Comment: you provided a sample just for one table. take this fiddle, fill it with data and put link into your post when it is ready http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa6e0f

Comment: The encounter table is pretty much what the results are, I just need to include a column counting how many players have a health greater than zero.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17ba5e/1

Comment: Unclear? @Alex, you already gave the answer!

Comment: It pointed me to the right direction, thank you!